# Many-to-many relationship in play framework java

Tags: java, playframework, many-to-many, ebean

I am trying to use many to many approach product has many to many relation with shop
**Product.java**

```
package models;
@Entity
public class Product extends Model {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="product_gen", sequenceName="product_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="product_gen")
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    public Float price;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<Shop>();

    public Product(String name, float price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public static List<Product> all(){
        return find.all();
    }
    public static Model.Finder<Long, Product> find = new Model.Finder(Long.class, Product.class);

    public static Product create(String name,float price) {
        Product product = new Product(name, price);
        product.save();
        product.saveManyToManyAssociations("shops");
        return product;
    }




}
```

play created a table product_shop which has shop_id and product_id as foreign key but not able to store any value in product_shop table on adding a product
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you add an     @JoinTable(name = "product_shop") just behind @ManyToMany

Comment: still the same output

Answer (score 5):

I have `Apps` and `Users`. Each app can have several Users, each User can use several Apps.

In your case, you can replace `App` with `Product` and `User` with `Shop`

Here is my working code under Play! 2.2.2

Evolutions of DB :

```
create table app_user (
  id                varchar(40) not null,
  constraint pk_fb_user primary key (id)
);

create table app (
  id                    varchar(40) not null,
  name                  text,
  constraint pk_app_id primary key (id)
);

create table membership (
  app_id                varchar(40) not null,
  app_user_id           varchar(40) not null,
  constraint fk_membership_app_id foreign key (app_id) references app,
  constraint fk_membership_app_user_id foreign key (app_user_id) references app_user
);
```

Model App

```
@Entity
public class App extends Model {

    @Id
    public UUID id;

    @Column
    public String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "membership")
    public List<User> users;

    ....
}
```

Model User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
// user is reserved keyword in DB
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public UUID id;

}
```

I don't need to access Apps of a User so I didn't have an App field in User.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking into an embedded id.

Make a class for your primary key

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductShopKey {
 public Long productId;
 public Long shopId;

 public boolean equals(Object object) {
  if(object isInstanceOf ProductShopKey){
   ProductShopKey key = (ProductShopKey) object
   if(this.productId == key.productId
      && this.shopId == key.shopId
     ){
        return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 public int hashCode() {
  return productId.hashCode() + shopId.hashCode();
 }
}
```

Then make an entity for the class

```
@entity
public class ProductShop {
 @EmbeddedId
 public ProductShopKey psKey = new ProductShopKey();

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
 public Product product;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
 public Shop shop;

 //Extra value to go in your join table
 public String someValue;
 ...
}
```

Then `Shop` and `Product` each have a one to many relationship with `ProductShop`

Inserting entries into the table is done manually

```
ProductShop ps = new ProductShop();
ps.psKey.productId = someProductId;
ps.psKey.shopId = someShopId;
ps.someValue = someValue;
ps.save();
```

Comment: getting error on doing this `PersistenceException: SERIOUS ERROR: The hashCode() and equals() methods *MUST* be implemented on Embedded bean class models.ProductShopKey as it is used as an Id for class models.ProductShop`

Comment: Yeah. Just implement anything it tells you to however you think it should be done. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: still no data is inserted in product_shop table

Comment: I've given an example of how inserting is done. Unfortunately it needs to be done manually as far as I know. I've also taken `someValue` out of the key class and moved it into the entity class since it isn't part of the composed key. Hopefully this helps.